# DTO design for Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, dto

Environment :

Spring 3

Angular JS

Tomcat

Issue :

I am migrating a legacy application from struts2 to spring MVC REST with angular JS as UI.
This is a typical SPA.
For a typical flow in struts2 (e.g: subscribe to a product) , there are multipule actions and JPSs involved , multipule steps.
The corresponding Spring MVC archirtecture has matching controller calls for every step (e.g: 3 steps - 3 controllers)

My question is regarding DTO:

1)Should the application have a single DTO to pass for the entire flow / steps ? 
That is for all the flow/steps same DTO will be used.

2)Have a separate DTO(stripped down version) for every step/action. This will cause only required data to be transferred.

Since my DTO is pretty complex , it would be difficult to pass entire DTO for every step

Comment: The http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ would be better place for this question.

Comment: @KarolLewandowski when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Thanks. I will do it next time.